# I want to extract link from a HTML page to download my images, and I have several thousand of these HTML files. How do I go about this?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, html

so I have HTML files which have a specific portion I'd like to extract. These HTML addresses are in a text file. A sample HTML webpage, taken from this textfile would look like this, and I'd want to get part 009514HB.JPG which is different for every HTML file.

My .txt file would be something like this -

```
    https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd0c97267166cd653c8
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfcfc97267166cd61ff4
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd0c97267166cd6310a
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd0c97267166cd6310b
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfcfc97267166cd61ff5
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd0c97267166cd64278
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfcfc97267166cd61ff6
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfcfc97267166cd61ff7
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd0c97267166cd63c1b
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfcfc97267166cd619b1
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfcfc97267166cd619b4
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfcfc97267166cd625a3
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd0c97267166cd64844
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfcfc97267166cd619ba
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd0c97267166cd63ce3
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd0c97267166cd64437
https://www.dermquest.com/image-library/image/5044bfd1c97267166cd67203
```

and if I click open one of those html pages using a text editor I can find the information I need..

```
   *** some code here***
<figure>
         <a href="/imagelibrary/large/009514HB.JPG" target="_blank" class="preview-image"><img src="/imagelibrary/medium/009514HB.JPG" alt="acne keloidalis nuchae"/></a>
</figure>
...
```

Now I would like to get these numbers from various HTML files, and then append these numbers to `https://www.dermquest.com/imagelibrary/large`. For example, I would want my final txt file to have urls which are like this, [slightly NSFW] `https://www.dermquest.com/imagelibrary/large/009514HB.JPG` This line would be easier for me to wget the images! I don't know a lot about SED or AWK so any sort of advice/help would be great.

Thanks!

tl;dr: The links point to a webpage not an image, so when I wget I'm downloading html pages rather than images I want. This is how I think I could do it but any better solutions would be helpful too!

Comment: Just wondering (haven't tried): Can't you just download these images automatically with a single `wget --base=https://www.dermquest.com/ --mirror localfile.html` or similar command, leaving all that "extracting" work you wish to do to wget?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the input files I suggest 
not trying to parse HTML with `awk`, `grep` and such but 
to use an HTML parser. For similar tasks I use [lynx](https://lynx.browser.org/), 
*the* text mode browser. To install it a 
simple `sudo apt install lynx` is sufficient. Then:

```
for file in *.html; do
    lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers $file >> links.txt
done
```

For your sample snippet it creates the following output:

```
file:///imagelibrary/large/009514HB.JPG
```

When done, the `file://` part needs to be replaced with a proper base URL:

```
sed -i 's|file://|https://www.dermquest.com|' links.txt
```

Result:

```
https://www.dermquest.com/imagelibrary/large/009514HB.JPG
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In the above code, could you please tell me if I should be replacing 'file' with my filename listings.txt, which has my list of urls? If I type your command as it is I don't see anything....

Comment: @ai_boy I don't get it. I thought you have a bunch of *.html files with `<a href="/imagelibrary/large/009514HB.JPG" …><img src="…" alt="…"/></a>` in them and wanted to extract those links to get a list of these URLs. When you do that via `lynx … file.html` then it prints `file:///imagelibrary/large/009514HB.JPG` because `lynx` doesn't know a better _base url_. Then apply the `sed` command to replace the text `file://` with `https://www.dermquest.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it down into steps, you want to:

1. Process a bunch of files (named `*.html`?).
2. Extract lines like `<a href="/imagelibrary/large/009514HB.JPG" ...`.
3. Extract the filename part ("`009514HB.JPG`").
4. Produce text using the filename part.

   ```
   find . -type f -name '*.html' -print0 | \
       xargs -0 -r grep --no-filename "a href=" | \
       grep -E -o '[0-9A-Z]+\.JPG'
   ```

Then, by wrapping the above inside a `for $()` construct, we get:

```
for i in $( find . -type f -name '*.html' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r grep --no-filename "a href=" | \
    grep -E -o '[0-9A-Z]+\.JPG'
          ) ; do
    echo "https://www.dermquest.com/imagelibrary/large/$i"
done
```

Of course, read `man find`, `man xargs`, `man grep`.

Comment: It says Xargs and grep not found... Am I just supposed to type this out in the command line?